# I need to restore db from dump and cannot do it

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.4, database-restore

I have a database dump at **D:/backup.dump**. I try to restore my database `min_ro`: I open psql.exe plugin. There are words

`min_ro=#`

Then I write restore command:

```
min_ro=# psql min_ro < D:/backup.dump
```

Then happens nothing. My database is not restored. What is wrong? It's first time using `psql`.

**Update.** I don't need psql only - I need to restore db from dump and cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

`psql` is not a SQL statement, so it doesn't make sense to enter that at the `psql` **prompt** which is there to run *SQL statements* (or `psql` meta commands).

```
c:\> psql min_ro < D:/backup.dump
```

needs to be entered on the (Windows) command line, **not** inside `psql`.

You can however just run the SQL script (which I assume your dump is) by using the `\i` ("include") meta command in `psql``

```
c:\> psql min_ro
min_ro=# \i D:/backup.dump
```

Comment: First you must go to folder where `psql.exe` is situated. For example it is `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL9.4/bin/`

Comment: @NewDevelop: you only need that if `psql` is not in the `PATH`. But your question was not "*how do I start `psql`*" but how to use the dump you have.

Comment: Look at the tile of question. _It's first time using psql._ Of cource it's not at PATH )

Answer (score 0):

When you restore your database at `pgAdminIII` (by right-click at database name then choice 'restore') you can't see `.dump` files at backup list by default. That was my mistake forced me to try another ways to restore DB from dump.

But if you simply change file types to `'All files'` you can restore your database from dump as usially.